# LimitedTreeMap in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, tree

I want to have a `map` that is ordered, but at the same time has a maximum number of elements. For example if I have three elements in the map with keys `1`, `2`, `3` and I add `4` to the map, the map should now contain `2`,`3`, `4` ( only the biggest three values are used). How can I achive this. How should I implement the `put` method. Any help is welcomed :)

```
class LimitedTreeMap<K extends Number, V> extends TreeMap<K, V> {

    int limitSize;

    public LimitedTreeMap(int limitSize) {
        this.limitSize = limitSize;
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        // Add logic for the desired behaviour
        return super.put(key, value);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the lowest key if reached the limit.

```
class LimitedTreeMap<Long, V> extends TreeMap<Long, V> {

    int limitSize;

    public LimitedTreeMap(int limitSize) {
        this.limitSize = limitSize;
    }

    @Override
    public V put(Long key, V value) {

        // Add logic for the desired behaviour
        V v = super.put(key, value);

        if (this.size() > limitSize)
            this.pollFirstEntry();

        return v;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the keys,
find the smallest,
check whether the key you want to add is larger and should be added at all,
add the new key (if necessary)
remove the smallest key if and only if the map now contains more than three elements

Obivously this will not work if you want the map to still return the three largest keys that were ever added to it after you remove a key. If you want that too you should consider adding all keys (sorted) and modifying `get` to never return a value for a key that is not in the top three instead (and iterator, delete etc. if you don't want them to access any elements after the first three either).